# Unable to acquire context: EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW:A native windowtype argument does not refer to a valid native window

Tags: android, native

I am developing an Android application entitled "Virtual companion using voice exchange. 
Now i encountered a problem after i build my Unity project into Android version. As i install and test my app over an Android phone, i received an error messages:  Unable to acquire context: EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW:A native windowtype argument does not refer to a valid native window.
What must be the problem here? Can you help me fix this?

Thank you very much.